# Warping a GeoTIFF File (Error1: Cannot open CSV)

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, gdal, gdalwarp

Here is my code for the script :

```
import os
import subprocess as sub
# get your files
path = r'C:\Users\User\Downloads\jalna\pdf\test'
files = [os.path.join(path, f) for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith('.tif')]
# now run gdalwarp on each file
i = 0
for f in files:
    i+=1
    basename = os.path.basename(f)
    print(basename)
    newname = os.path.join('C:\Users\UserDownloads\jalna', str(i) + '_warped.tif')
    # set up call
    my_call = [r'C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\OSGeo4W.bat',
                'gdalwarp', f, newname, '-cutline', 'neat.csv', '-cwhere', 'id=1', '-crop_to_cutline']
    # call it
    print 'Using gdalwarp on {0} to convert it to {1}'.format(f, newname)
    p = sub.Popen(my_call, stdout=sub.PIPE, stdin=sub.PIPE)

    stdout, stdin = p.communicate()
    if p.returncode != 0:
        print stdout
        print stderr
```

I want to run this command from OSGeo4W Shell:

```
gdalwarp 1.tif 1_c.tif -cutline neat.csv -cwhere id=1 -crop_to_cutline
```

But getting the error:

> ERROR 1: Cannot open neat.csv.

Comment: Your command-line has "neatline.csv" and your script has "neat.csv"

Comment: I am sorry it was neat.csv, I typed it wrong here.

Comment: Full path to `neat.csv` ??